# 301 redirects for specific Wordpress URL's else 301 everything to homepage on new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I seem to be going around in circles with this at the moment which is becoming frustrating...

I am trying to 301 redirect numerous Wordpress URL's to their new equivalents on a new domain from the old domain's .htaccess and for everything else, apply a sitewide redirect to the new domain's homepage.

Every time I try and implement a redirect for the entire site, it seems to override any redirects for individual pages though. I can't seem to get **both** ways to work.

Here is an example:-

```
#Sitewide
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com

#Individuals
RedirectMatch 301 /page1 http://newdomain.com/page-1/
RedirectMatch 301 /page2/ http://newdomain.com/page-2/
RedirectMatch 301 /dfgeds/ http://newdomain.com/lpojpohj/
```

And I have tried literally LOTS of approaches and methods which include:-

- RedirectMatch 301
- Redirect 301
- RewriteRule
- RewriteCond with RewriteRule

I am aware of complications trying to get .htaccess directives to work in Wordpress websites but I have also tried placing rules above the defaults, below the defaults or with the defaults.

So far, I have not found anything that works for every instance I am after yet I am sure it must just be something obvious at play here.

- Which directives should I be using?
- Which order should they be in?
- Where in the Wordpress .htaccess should be positioned?
- Have you got an example you could offer that you'd expect to work for me to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your #sitewide redirect bellow #Individuals redirects so that it can not override your individuals requests,

```
#Individuals
RedirectMatch 301 /page1 http://newdomain.com/page-1/
RedirectMatch 301 /page2/ http://newdomain.com/page-2/
RedirectMatch 301 /dfgeds/ http://newdomain.com/lpojpohj/
#Sitewide
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com
```

Comment: Great, that works well. I, at some point, tried different orders but I think it must have all got messed up with conflicting directives in. Thanks.